# Android google cloud messaging issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hey can anybody please tell me what is the problem with my server or code or Google Cloud Messaging,because my App sometimes sends messages to other devices and sometimes it doesn't. Please help me sort out this problem, it's really annoying me. I Don't know what is the problem, at some point I thought the problem was with my Internet connection but it's not because my Internet connection is also working fine.
I searched a lot but couldn't find any good source.

```
if(!Constants.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            try 
            {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                if(message.startsWith("{\"From"))
                {
                    //Do Message received activity

                    ReceivedMessageModel obj = gson.fromJson(message, ReceivedMessageModel.class);

                    IAppMessages iMessages = DBManager.singleInstance(context.getApplicationContext());;
                    String contactNumber = iMessages.InsertNewlyRecievedAppMessage(obj);

                    displayMessage(context, obj.Message);
                    // notifies user
                    generateNotification(context, obj.Message, contactNumber);

                }
                else if(message.startsWith("{\"ContactNumber"))
                {
                    //Do New Contact activity
                    NewContactsResponseModel obj = gson.fromJson(message, NewContactsResponseModel.class);
                    List<ContactResponseModel> list = new ArrayList<ContactResponseModel>();
                    ContactResponseModel model = new ContactResponseModel();
                    model.UserId = obj.SqlUserId;
                    model.ContactNumber = obj.ContactNumber;
                    list.add(model);

                    IAppContacts iContact = new ContactsService(context.getApplicationContext());
                    iContact.UpdateMappedAppContactsResponse(list);

                    String userName = iContact.GetAppContactName(obj.ContactNumber);

                    displayMessage(context, userName + " has Joined OyeApp!");
                    // notifies user
                    generateNotification(context, userName + " has Joined OyeApp!", obj.ContactNumber);

                }
                else if(message.startsWith("{\"GroupId"))
                {
                    GroupsModel group = gson.fromJson(message, GroupsModel.class);
                    iGroup.CreateGroup(group);

                    displayMessage(context, group.GroupName + " has been created!");
                    // notifies user
                    generateNotification(context, "You are added to ", group.GroupName);

                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
```